# How to pass current route name to other component in 'react-navigation' that is not inside App Container

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have the custom navbar, that is located next to my AppContainer and I want to do some logic based on the current routeName of my navigator, how can I do that?

I've tried to pass navigation as ref, as described here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html but in that navigation prop I don't have the current route name.

```
const [navigation, setNavigation] = useState(null);

<AppContainer ref={nav => setNavigation(nav)} />
<NavBar navigation={navigation} />
```

```
const NavBar = ({ navigation }) => {
    return <div>{navigation.state.routeName}</div> 
};

// routeName is undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current `routeName` of a navigator object like below:

```
const {state: {routes, index}} = navigation;
const currentRouteName = routes[index];
```

actually all routes of a navigator object are in `routes` property which you define them when you create your navigator; the `index` property is the number of the index in the `routes` that app currently is recently navigated to that.

**Note**
if your current `routes[index]` is an inner navigator itself (like a stackNavigator within a drawerNavigator) you should do the same above on the inner navigator to reach the real routeName that application is currently navigated to it.

However it seems your case isn't much complex and you can get the routeName you want by applying the above code on your `navigation` object only once.